# Imported Script doesn't load when a component is mounted - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I am working on a React JS application. I have three main `Routes` which are `/login`, `/register` and, `/app`. In the app component I have imported a `swipe.js` script that's only necessary for `/app` component and not for the rest. But when I run the app, it automatically loads the script  on `/login` and `/register` as well, this is the first issue. The second issue is, when I login or register, then I wrote a script to get redirected to `/app` component and it is done successfully, but the as the `swipe.js` is already loaded, the `events` and `functions` from `swipe.js` doesn't work on `/app`. I don't know what is the problem.

**Index.js Code**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//Styles
import './Components/assets/css/bootstrap.css'
//Scripts
import 'bootstrap'
//Components
import App from './App';
import Register from './Components/register'
import Login from './Components/login'
//Routing
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';



ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Route path={'/app'} component={App} />
        <Route path={'/login'} component={Login} />
        <Route path={'/register'} component={Register} />
    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js - /app**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
//Scripts
import 'bootstrap'
import 'popper.js'
//Custom Scripts
import './Components/assets/js/swipe.min'

// Components
import Navigation from './Components/navigation'
import SideBar from './Components/sidebar'
import Chat from './Components/chat'
import Compose from './Components/compose-modal'


export class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
 
  this.state = {
    
  }
 }

componentDidMount(){
  console.log("App Component Mounted...");
 }
 
 render() {
  return (
   <div className="layout">
    <Navigation />
    <SideBar />
    <Chat />
    <Compose />
   </div>
  )
 }
}

export default App;
```

**Login & Register Components**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './assets/css/bootstrap.css'
import './scss/auth.scss'
import AuthImage from './assets/img/chat-bg.jpg'
import Profile from './assets/img/avatars/avatar-male-1.jpg'
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


import {app,  Cookies} from '../Shared/Globals'

export class register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             fname:'',
             lname:'',
             email:'',
             pass:'',
             pass2:'',
             formValid : false,
             regFormBtn : 'Join Now',
             formError : {
                 error : false,
                 data : null
             }, 
             registered : false
        }

        this.handleRegisterForm = this.handleRegisterForm.bind(this)
        this.registerUser = this.registerUser.bind(this)
    }


    handleRegisterForm(event){
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]:event.target.value
        })
        if(this.state.fname !== '' &&
           this.state.lname !== '' &&
           this.state.email !== '' &&
           this.state.pass  !== '' &&
           this.state.pass2 !== '' 
          ){
            this.setState({
                formValid : true
            })
          } else{
            this.setState({
                formValid : false
            })
          }
    }

    registerUser(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        
        if(this.state.formValid){
            this.setState({
                regFormBtn : 'Joining ...',
                formValid : false
            })
            app.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.pass)
            .then( res => {
                console.log(res);
                new Cookies().createCookie("uid", res.user.uid, '10 minutes');
                this.setState({
                    regFormBtn : 'Success !'
                })
                this.resetForm();
                this.setState({
                    registered : true
                })
            })
            .catch( error =>{
                console.log(error);
                this.setState({
                    formValid : true,
                    regFormBtn : 'Try Again'
                })
                let err = {...this.state}
                err.formError.error = true
                this.setState({
                    err
                })
                switch(error.code){
                    case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
                    case 'auth/weak-password':
                    case 'auth/network-request-failed':
                        {
                            let err = {...this.state}
                            err.formError.data = error.message
                            this.setState({
                                err
                            })
                            break;
                        } 
                        default:
                }
            })
        } else{
            console.log("Form is invalid");
        }

    }
    
    
    render() {
        let e = '';
        if(this.state.formError.error){
           e =  <div className='error'>{this.state.formError.data}</div>
        } else{ e = '' }
        if(this.state.registered){
            return <Redirect to='/app' />
        }
        return (
            <>
                <div className='container auth-row'>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col-6'>
                            <div className='auth-img'>
                                <img src={AuthImage} alt='auth' />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className='col-6' >
            <div className='auth'>
                <div className='auth-head'> Join Our Chat Community Now !</div>
                <div className='auth-form'>

                    <form className='row' method='POST' onSubmit={this.registerUser}>
                        <div className='col-12'> {e} </div>
                        <div className='rcaInput col-6'>
                            <input type='text' placeholder='First Name' name='fname' onChange={this.handleRegisterForm} />
                        </div>
                        <div className='rcaInput col-6'>
                            <input type='text' placeholder='Last Name' name='lname' onChange={this.handleRegisterForm} />
                        </div>
                        <div className='rcaInput col-12'>
                            <input type='email' placeholder='Email Address' name='email' onChange={this.handleRegisterForm} />
                        </div>
                        <div className='rcaInput col-12'>
                            <input type='Password' placeholder='Password' name='pass' onChange={this.handleRegisterForm} />
                        </div>
                        <div className='rcaInput col-12'>
                            <input type='Password' placeholder='Repeat Password' name='pass2' onChange={this.handleRegisterForm} />
                        </div>
                        <div className='btn-space col-12'>
                            <button className='rcaBtn' type='submit' disabled={!this.state.formValid}> {this.state.regFormBtn} </button>
                            <div className='small-font' style={{paddingTop:'10px'}}> Already have an account ? <Link to={'/login'} > Login Now</Link> </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default register
```

Comment: why are you trowing siwipe.min into global? import it in CDM, are you using wabpack to bundle your code?

Comment: @Roy.B yes, I am using `create-react-app` Its a React JS app. What do you mean by 'trowing siwipe.min into global' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app.js file you can modify it slightly:

```
let swipe;

export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { swipeLoaded: false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    swipe = require('./...swipe.js'); // require your swipe file here
    this.state = { swipeLoaded: true };
  }
}
```

To prevent other issues in your render (because setting state in CDM will cause a re-render) add this to the render():

```
if (!this.state.swipeLoaded) return null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked perfect. But is it an efficient approach ?

Comment: Not sure whether it's totally 'efficient'. Common enough that it's the first thing I thought of and I've seen it in quite a few places.